# Make all checkboxes unchecked, then check some

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to make all checkboxes on page unchecked when loading the page and then at the same time if some of them were checked save that in a variable and make them checked. I have tried with this

```
$('input[id^="chkbx_"]').prop("checked", false);

var a;
if ($("#chkbx_program_a").prop("checked")){
a= "true";
}else{
a= "false";
}

     $('#chkbx_program_b').prop('checked', a);
}
});
```

But still all checkboxes are unchecked.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/EUtfr/

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it doesn't work is that the program logic is in the wrong order. First you uncheck all checkboxes, *then* check if one of them is checked--of course it is not, because you just unchecked it. You could move the part where you save its status to the beginning and it would work, or even better:

```
$('input[id^="chkbx_"]').not("#chkbx_program_a").prop("checked", false);
```

This will uncheck everything except that one checkbox.

Comment: But that is not what I want. I first want all unchecked, then in the next step, if some were checked by the user, I want to save that and when the page loads again, I want that checkbox to be checked still.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand why whether you want to check #chkbx_program_b when #chkbx_program_a is checked. if you want to do so then you can do this.

`$e = $("#chkbx_program_b").prop("checked",$("chkbx_program_a").prop("checked"));
$('input[id^="chkbx_"]').not($e).prop("checked", false);`

Comment: That still makes all unchecked. I want to first make all unchecked, then if some were checked, for example program_b, I want that checked when the page loads again.

Comment: I think you are confused. Frist if you reload the page all of them will be unchecked, so you just have to make them checked. And you cant do that using JS because the javascript or jquery also refreshes when page refresh so all the variables will be destroyed. you should either save it on server side or inside cookies.

Comment: I suspected that, but it was worth a try. Maybe I will try to save them on the server side.